# Seg. Fault When Pushing a Pointer on a std::vector

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have profiled the following code with Valgrind and got the following:

`Use of uninitialised value of size 8`
`invalid read of size 8`

when executing this line:

```
compuMethod->keywordlist->push_back(keyword);
```

However, I have clearly initialized `keyword`...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Keyword;
class CompuMethod;

typedef std::vector<Keyword*> KeywordList;
std::map<std::string, CompuMethod*> AllCompuMethods;

class Keyword
{
    private:
        std::string _name;

    public:
        Keyword(std::string name) : _name(name) {}
        virtual ~Keyword() {}
        std::string GetName() { return(_name); }
};

class CompuMethod
{
    public:
        CompuMethod(){}
        ~CompuMethod(){}
        KeywordList* keywordlist;

};

int main()
{
    CompuMethod* compuMethod = new CompuMethod();
    Keyword* keyword = new Keyword("terminal");
    compuMethod->keywordlist->push_back(keyword);

    //Call delete for each new
    return 0;
}
```

I am obviously overlooking something. What am I doing on this line:

`Keyword* keyword = new Keyword("terminal");`

that is NOT initializing `keyword`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keywordlist` is a pointer to `std::vector<Keyword*>`

You can't simply push items into it.

Use following to allocate memory for the pointer to vector in the Constructor

`CompuMethod(){keywordlist = new  KeywordList();}`

And accordingly update the Destructor

`~CompuMethod(){ delete keywordlist; }`

**Edit** :

greyfade comment -

"*But don't forget the copy/move ctor and operator= to properly handle the pointer. Otherwise, you'll end up with double-frees*"

Comment: But don't forget the copy/move ctor and `operator=` to properly handle the pointer. Otherwise, you'll end up with double-frees. (Or better ,use a smart pointer.)

Answer (score 2):

`keyword` is initialised correctly.  The problem is that you didn't allocate
`compuMethod->keywordlist`

You should either make `keywordlist` a `KeywordList` rather than a pointer or allocate it in `CompuMethod()` (deleting it in the destructor)